# Como poner fecha de nacimiento en un input date

Tags: javascript, html

Hola lo que quiero hacer es que al dar click en el **input** el calendario que muestra comience en el año 1900 como por defecto pero no muestre la fecha en el input antes de seleccionar una fecha, intente con **value** pero eso muestra la fecha sin haber seleccionado.

Comment: Para poder ayudarte no olvides poner un [mcve] de lo que llevas hecho hasta ahora.

Comment: Prueba utlilizando JQueryUI tiene un componente llamado Datepicker, el cual puede resolver tu problema facilmente.

Comment: Intentare con JQueryUI es interesante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo con jQuery si deseas utilizar Js:

```js
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
firstDay: 1
});

$("#datepicker").click(function () {
$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", "-117y");
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Año Fijo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.datepicker-es.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
Fecha:
<div >
<input id="datepicker"></input></div>
<hr />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: En stack snippet, en la parte del HTML se puede colocar directamente el innerHTML de body. Por otro lado ¿para qué usar jQuery en un caso tan sencillo?

Comment: @Rubén por que sencillo, no sabemos si más adelante este proyecto crecera y tendra que utilizar JS u otros componentes, debemos mirar mas aya de lo que pensemos, y esto para el recien empieza.

Answer (score 1):

Debes usar onClick y al menos una línea de JavaScript. Ejemplo

```html
<input id="fecha" type="date" onclick="this.value = '1900-01-01';"/>
```